# "self.fetchController performFetch:nil" make table view data source methods called all the way

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I use Core Data in my App, just use this method only once in viewDidLoad. when I add new Entity(that is pressing a bar button item) just one time,the table view data source methods will perform all the way till I click stop button in Xcode. and the log will show the same count of fetch objects(always 1) for thousands times. I put the NSlog... func in "tableview: nuberOfRowsInSections.." method. so can anyone help figure this out. thanks you.

Comment: Please provide you insertion code and your datasource methods. and what do you mean by `_fetchController performFetch:nil`?

Comment: It's NSFetchResultsController's method: - (BOOL)performFetch:(NSError **)error.
and data source methods:
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> info = [self.fetchController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"count: %d", [info numberOfObjects]);
    return [info numberOfObjects];
}

Comment: You will need to make your fetched results controller code and insertion code available, also your table delegation methods (please add them in the question so they would be readable). There are a few options here, one would be that you perform the fetch or create the FRC again and again, or you update your data after each table update.

Comment: Can I send my whole project to you by mail if possible?

Comment: I would like to help, however, the point here is to share our problems and solutions so others may benefit from it. You can send me your project and I will then publish my findings or edit your question.

Comment: That will be cool, I've found you mail address and have sent my zip file to you(from ibackr@gmail.com), thanks to help.

Comment: I've added the missing part of the question in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source what I saw was:

A template core data project with main entity `EDLabel`.
The implementation file of `EDLabel` declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * labelDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * labelName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rowNum;
```

The fetch request (used by the FRC):

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *des = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EDLabel" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"labelDate" ascending:NO]; 
req.entity = des;
req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
```

Insertion code:

```
-(void)addNewLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    EDLabel *edLabel = (EDLabel *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EDLabel"
                                                                inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    edLabel.labelName = @"New Label";
    edLabel.labelDate = [NSDate date];
    if(![self.context save:nil]) NSLog(@"Save failed!");
}
```

The problematic issue was the cell configuration method:

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EDLabel *label = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    label.rowNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];//<-- this is the problem
    //some more configurations
}
```

Since this code is called each time the main context is updated (if there are any changes to the objects of the FRC), and this code modify the data itself (since it reset the `rowNum` property), we got an infinit loop of updates at the end of the main loop (when the main context call for `processPendingChanges`.

To remedy this issue, either remove the update line (since the sort in the view is done by the insertion date), or test to see if there was a change in the `rowNum` by using `NSNumber` `compare:` method.

Comment: It's very clear and have solved my problem, thanks again, you rock ~~